# C++ Gdiplus::Font changing font size and family

Tags: c++, fonts, gdi+, font-size, font-family

Look this code

```
Gdiplus::Graphics g(hDC);
Gdiplus::Font *f = new Font(L"Times new roman", 16);
Gdiplus::SolidBrush b(Gdiplus::Color(255,0,0,0));

g.DrawString(L"Hello", 5, f, &Gdiplus::StringFormat(), &b);

// Now i want to change font styles
// using f->setSize() or f->setFontFamily().

g.DrawString(L"Hello", 5, f, &Gdiplus::StringFormat(), &b);
```

I want to change font size and family using the same "f" variable (actually i'm using a pointer to f). Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you have to ceate a new instance of the Font class to alter the style.

Comment: I don't know what "doesn't work" means.  I can only guess that you don't use the Font() constructor overload that lets you set the style.